# Jquery close bootstrap modal dialog completedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code to close bootstrap modal using jquery

```
//Start to hide bootstrap modal
    $('#continue-last-level').modal('hide'); //Line 1
//End

//Codes to execute another function 
        $.ajax({                             //Line 2
        url : '/qst/continue_last_level/',
        type : 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data : 'performance_level='+performance_level,
        success : function (data) 
        {
            localStorage.setItem("key", 60*3*data.total_questions);
            localStorage.setItem("question_id", data.first_question_id);
            localStorage.setItem("question_number", data.question_number);
            view_question_template(performance_level);
        }
        });
    }
//End code
```

My problem is after I execute code at **Line 1**, I want to execute the codes at **Line 2**, the bootstrap modal was hidden but there is a **div** still not hide... here is my screen short for your reference...

Image 1
[image]

After I clicked yes...let say to call function to execute code at **Line 2** The modal was hidden, but...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#continue-last-level').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `hide` method is asynchronous:

> ### [`.modal('hide')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods)
>
> Manually hides a modal. **Returns to the caller before the modal has actually been hidden** (i.e. before the `hidden.bs.modal` event occurs).

So you need to account for that in your code and use the `hidden` event that Bootstrap provides:

```
$('#continue-last-level').one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // modal is now hidden
    // your code here
}).modal('hide');
```